# VS 2008 c++ debug: does not show local variables for a specific function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug a little c++ code I wrote.
It has several functions, all in the same c++ file, something like

```
static void b( int i ) {
     int k = i * 2;
}
static void a( int j ) {
     for( int l = 0; l < j ; l++ ) {
         b( l + j );
     }
}
int main( void ) {
    a( 4 );
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code in debug mode and I put a break point inside function `b`.
The code compiles well and the debugger stops at the breakpoint **BUT**
when I try to examine the value of local variable `k` I get

> CXX0017: Error: symbol "k" not found

I can see the value of `i` - the input argument.
Moreover, if I click of the calling function `a` in the call stack I can examine there both argument variable `j` and local variable `l`...

Has anyone ever came across such a wierd situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:  I was dumb enough to corrupt my stack. I did it very elegantly, so I was still able to see the "call stack", but information regarding local variables in a specific frame was corrupted. Handling memory with more care and respect solved this annoying issue.

Thanks [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241536/john-dibling) for your effort.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that `k` is not constructed when your breakpoint hits and is destroyed before you get a chance to examine it.

Try adding a line of code *after* where `k` is being initialized, and break there instead.

```
static void b( int i ) {
     int k = i * 2;
     bool bk = true; // <== BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

Comment: John, thank you for the answer, but the situation is much more complex. My code is naturally more complex than the sample I posted for illustrative purpose only. I have many local variables **all** not shown in debug. It's not the first time I debug in VS this is something I NEVER came across. very weird. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Shai:  Are you *certian* that you're not building in Release mode?  Do you have optimizations enabled in Debug mode?

Comment: I think I got it - I corrupted my stack...

Comment: @Shai:  Ah, yes.  That will happen. :)